# Why should we call sanctum/csrf-cookie on Laravel Sanctum

Tags: laravel, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I was reading [document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#csrf-protection), and one question occurred. Why would we need to call this endpoint `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` to get CSRF protection when login?

I understand what CSRF is, and per my understanding, the practice that Laravel uses to prevent CSRF is to set a cookie `xsrf-token` on browser and then Angular or some framework would automatically attach the cookie to header as `x-xsrf-token`, and it's also called `server side double submit` as one of the practices to prevent CSRF

However, I just don't get why on Laravel Sanctum we have to manually call `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` before login. With `Web guard`, this protection is automatic after login without any manual work before login.

My question is what is the benefit or logic for calling `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` before login rather than automatically sending `x-csrf-cookie` to browser via response after login?

Anyone could help to further explain will be so much appreciated.

Comment: this just an example of route you could change it as you want

Comment: @Joseph Thanks. But I don't quite get what you mean. I know the route could be changed as we want, but I don't quite get the pattern.